# Find the k dict items whose values are the closest to a certain value

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary, nearest-neighbor

Let's say we want to find the 2 items which have their value the closest to 10:

```
A = {'abc': 12.3, 'def': 17.3, 'dsfsf': 18, 'ppp': 3.2, "jlkljkjlk": 9.23}
```

It works with:

```
def nearest(D, centre, k=10):
    return sorted([[d, D[d], abs(D[d] - centre)] for d in D], key=lambda e: e[2])[:k]

print(nearest(A, centre=10, k=2))
```

> [['jlkljkjlk', 9.23, 0.7699999999999996], ['abc', 12.3, 2.3000000000000007]]

**But is there a Python built-in way to do this and/or a more optimized version when the dict has a much larger size (hundreds of thousands of items)?**

Comment: You can use partitioning with numpy

Comment: @MadPhysicist This would require to manually split the dict into a list for the strings, and a numpy array for the values, and then do all manually, or do you mean there's a ready to use function for this?

Comment: This looks more like a task for a binary tree, or a kde-tree (in case the data is multidimensional).

Comment: @Basj. `np.argpartition(np.abs(np.subtractlist(d.values())), 2)` will get you pretty close since the order of `keys` and `values` is the same. You'd probably get better mileage doing it the operations in place. I can't think of a one line solution if that's what you're asking.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Can you post an anwser with this (it would be interesting for future ref)? You also need to subtract `centre` to the dict values, before taking `abs`.

Comment: @Basj. There are a lot of typos there. I'm on mobile. The subtract was the to remove the center. I don't have a complete answer though.

Comment: Did you mean `def nearest(D, centre=10, k=2):`?

Answer (score 7):

If you do not mind using Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
closest = (pd.Series(A) - 10).abs().sort_values()[:2]
#jlkljkjlk    0.77
#abc          2.30
closest.to_dict()
#{'jlkljkjlk': 0.7699999999999996, 'abc': 2.3000000000000007}
```

Comment: Nice! Is there something similar in numpy (to avoid another dependancy)?

Comment: Numpy is not good for handling heterogeneous arrays, and in your case, the array is heterogeneous (string and float).

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`heapq.nsmallest()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/heapq.html#heapq.nsmallest):

```
from heapq import nsmallest
A = {'abc': 12.3, 'def': 17.3, 'dsfsf': 18, 'ppp': 3.2, 'jlkljkjlk': 9.23}
def nearest(D, centre, k=10):
    return [[x, D[x], abs(D[x] - centre)] for x in nsmallest(k, D, key=lambda x: abs(D[x] - centre))]

print(nearest(A, centre=10, k=2))
# [['jlkljkjlk', 9.23, 0.7699999999999996], ['abc', 12.3, 2.3000000000000007]]
```

As far as time complexity, this runs in `O(n log(k))` time instead of `O(n log(n))` of the solution based on sorting the dictionary.

Comment: Oh, we already have an `nsmallest` :D I'll remove my answer. It's good to note here that this would be O(n log(k)) instead of O(n log(n)).

Answer (score 2):

Given you need to perform a lookup quite often, we can make this an *O(log n)* algorithm, by first storing the data in a *sorted* list:

```
from operator import itemgetter

ks = sorted(A.items(), key=itemgetter(1))
vs = list(map(itemgetter(1), ks))
```

Then for each item we can use the [**`bisect.bisect_left`**](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/bisect.html#bisect.bisect_left) point to determine the insertion point. We can then check the two surrounding values, to check the smallest, and return the corresponding key. It is also possible that

```
from bisect import bisect_left
from operator import itemgetter

def closests(v):
    idx = bisect_left(vs, v)
    i, j = max(0, idx-1), min(idx+2, len(ks))
    part = ks[i:j]
    return sorted([[*pi, abs(pi[-1]-v)] for pi in part], key=itemgetter(-1))[:2]
```

The above might not look as an improvement, but here we will always evaluate *at most* three elements in the `sorted(..)`, and `bisect_left` will evaluate a *logarithmic* number of elements.

For example:

```
>>> closests(1)
[['ppp', 3.2, 2.2], ['jlkljkjlk', 9.23, 8.23]]
>>> closests(3.2)
[['ppp', 3.2, 0.0], ['jlkljkjlk', 9.23, 6.03]]
>>> closests(5)
[['ppp', 3.2, 1.7999999999999998], ['jlkljkjlk', 9.23, 4.23]]
>>> closests(9.22)
[['jlkljkjlk', 9.23, 0.009999999999999787], ['abc', 12.3, 3.08]]
>>> closests(9.24)
[['jlkljkjlk', 9.23, 0.009999999999999787], ['abc', 12.3, 3.0600000000000005]]
```

The "loading" phase thus takes *O(n log n)* (with *n* the number of elements). Then if we generalize the above method to fetch *k* elements (by increasing the slice), it would take *O(log n + k log k)* to perform a lookup.

Comment: This is only getting 2 items. For `k` items, it's actually `O(k log(n))` (because of `part = ks[i:j]`). Also, you're ignoring the initial sort, but agreed that if you need to perform many lookups, it's a good investment.

Comment: @slider: no that would be *O(k log k + log n)* :) and indeed here the time complexity is the one for the *lookup*, not for the "loading".

Comment: Oh that's right. `bisect_left` is only once. But why k log k? It should just be O(k + log(n)).

Comment: Oh because of the next sort.

Comment: @slider: because we use a `sorted(..)` here as well, which requires *O(m log m)* (with *m* the list to slice), since *m = O(k)*, this thus yields *O(k log k + log n)*

Comment: @slider: exactly :)

Comment: Although if you go radially outwards from `idx` choosing the minimum difference element from either side, I think you can build the list of k elements sorted by difference in *O(k)* time.

Comment: @slider: you can indeed implement some sort of "zig-zag" function that enumerates these elements. It is however a bit tricky: if there is an element with exactly that value, then we of course yield that value, but then we need to look for both the element on the left, and right. Furthermore if the value is smaller than the smallest value, or larger than the largest, there is no next, so checking bounds makes it more complicated. But if I find sometime, I will try to implement it correctly :)

Comment: Yes, it will be pretty tedious with probably very little practical gain.